# stall dc motor 12 volt for long time

Tags: resistors, motor, dc, load

hi every one i make water cooling system for dc motor 12 volt 
how can i make the dc motor hot to test the system ?
whan i stall the dc motor the wires get very hot before that effect the motor 
and i tried to connected with riss 2 ohms and 1 ohm 
and the same problem .
here the part i used 
i am mechanical student [riss ohm](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10PCS-LOT-Ceramic-Cement-Resistor-10W-1-ohm-1R-Resistance-5-Error-DIY-Kit/32823758817.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3ec94c4dMUBo7y)
[dc motor 12 v](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/775-DC-Motor-DC-12V-36V-3500-9000-RPM-Ball-Bearing-Large-Torque-High-Power-low/32814556057.html?spm=2114.search0604.3.2.23312fc2Cqh707&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10065_10068_10870_5731315_319_317_5728815_10696_10084_5730415_10083_10618_10307_5731115_5731415_5731215_5731615_10867_328_10059_5729615_10884_5731515_10887_100031_321_322_10103_5731715-5731415_5731315,searchweb201603_2,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=4461c5de-ff47-41e3-ae61-5ab0ce1b075a-0&algo_pvid=4461c5de-ff47-41e3-ae61-5ab0ce1b075a)

Comment: You want to make the motor hot? And if you mean resistor, say resistor, not "riss ohm".

Comment: i mean i add a Resistance to the circuit to protect the motor

Comment: Then choose bigger wires for your motor. What wire gauge are you using at the moment? A series resistor will bring nothing, because nearly the whole heat is then dissipated in this resistors.

Comment: how can i protect the motor from burn ? you mean i should connect the resistance in parallel ?

Comment: Your water cooling should protect the motor :). No resistor at all is needed. Just slightly increase the voltage of the stalled motor until the necessary heat is disspated, that your water cooling is able to remove.

Comment: but here in this video in 2:48 min said this motor will reach 23 amp at stall !! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roINUVVpEbs   so i think i will need thicker wire and bigger power supply

Comment: 23A - so not a car starter or truck starter then ... truck starters can demand 1000A...

Comment: you dont need to apply the nominal voltage, clamp the motor to a variable power supply (should provide enough current) and slightly increase the voltage to the motor, until the motor becomes too hot with the connected water cooling. The maximum power your cooling system can remove is then V*I (under the assumption of very low resistance wires in comparison to the motor internal resistance).

Comment: Solar Mike , no i use 12v 180 watt power supply to power small pump and fan to cool and the motor

Comment: If you only have a constant power supply, use a mosfet with a proper driver and PWM and then slightly increase the duty cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the motor is stalled, the current is the applied voltage divided by the resistance of the armature winding. If the stall current is 23 amps with 12 volts applied, the resistance is 12/23 = 0.52 ohms. If you put 1 ohm in series, the stall current will be 12/1.52 = 7.9 amps. If you want the stall current to be equal to the 0.14 amps rated current of the motor, the armature plus series resistance must be 12/0.14 = 85.7 ohms.

If you don't want to buy or build a variable-voltage power supply, you can use resistors to have any stall current you want using the calculations described. Remember the power dissipated in the resistor will be the current squared multiplied by the resistance. The same is true of the power dissipated in the resistance of the armature winding.